# javascript to format to 2 decimal places from right to left

Tags: javascript, html

I have a use case such as
if I enter any number at first it should print 0.0 and that digit.

For example, if I enter 1 it should produce output as. The input should be restricted only for digits.  1--->0.01. Then on entering another digit it should produce output as
for example, if I add 2 12 --->0.12 Then if I add 3 it should produce output as  123 --->1.23 similarly for 4 it should give 12.34

I tried to enter from 1 to 9 and the output I expected was `1234567.8´ but it is giving`1234567.8900000001`

Please help me. Here is the code I tried

```js
function decimalCheck() {
  var dec = document.getElementById('number').value;
  var flag = 0;

  if (dec.length === 1) {
    document.getElementById('number').value = dec * 0.01;
    flag++;
  }


  if (dec.includes(".")) {
    var res = dec.substring(dec.indexOf(".") + 1);
    console.log("res value is .............." + res);
    if (res.length > 2) {
      dec = dec * 10;
      console.log("dec value is ............." + dec);
      document.getElementById('number').value = dec;
      //alert(dec);
    }
  }  
}
```

```html
Enter a number<input id="number" type="text" onkeyup="decimalCheck()" style="direction: rtl; "></input>
```

Comment: not related to the question, but: `<input>` is a self closing tag, there's no `</input>`

Comment: sorry Calvin Nunes I have edited the code

Comment: Why are you removing the snippet? It helps to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by adding `.toFixed(2)` ([fixed-point notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)) before you output the value. This will format to 2 decimals.

```js
function decimalCheck() {
  var dec = document.getElementById('number').value;
  var flag = 0;

  if (dec.length === 1) {
    document.getElementById('number').value = dec * 0.01;
    flag++;
  }


  if (dec.includes(".")) {
    var res = dec.substring(dec.indexOf(".") + 1);
    console.log("res value is .............." + res);
    if (res.length > 2) {
      dec = dec * 10;
      console.log("dec value is ............." + dec.toFixed(2));
      document.getElementById('number').value = dec.toFixed(2);
      //alert(dec);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
Enter a number<input id="number" type="text" onkeyup="decimalCheck()" style="direction: rtl;"></input>
```